# tell the same .net app that it's already running

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, process, mutex

I have a WPF app that I launch when the computer starts up with hidden window, so it works like a background task. It sometimes syncs with a certain website and when it finds out that there is some new date it shows a popup window. User should also can show a standard GUI in a way he would start a new app. I can detect by Mutex *in the new app* that it's new and I don't want it and will shut it down, but I've no idea to tell the older app that is should show GUI. Any idea how to do this? I don't need to post some string or something like that I just need to do a certain method in the older app.

Comment: `I don't need to post some string or something like that I just need to do a certain method in the older app.` Maybe you should.

Comment: You could set up a socket and send a message through that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send it a Windows Message using this API call.  Then in the hidden background app, you can check for this message, and show your UI:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lParam);
```

Here in your background app form, override the WndProc handler:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
    {
        // filter messages here for your purposes
        if (msg.wParam = MY_MESSAGE_CONSTANT) { ShowUI(); } 
        base.WndProc(ref msg);
    }
```

Another way to do this would be to use a FileSystemWatcher object, and watch a folder on your disk somewhere.  The first app could create a file there, and your background app would be notified and could show it's UI.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't know where to put it. When I copy-paste it in the MainWindow.xaml.cs it's just a block of errors.

Comment: Paste this into your MainWindow.xaml.cs file:   protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
            HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
            source.AddHook(WndProc);
        }

        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            // Handle messages...

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

Comment: Ok, done and how to use it? I need to send a message from App.g.cs and catch it somewhere; static DB class which works all the time would be idle.